# Assign a color to individual row numbers

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to assign an individual color to each row in a group. There are approximately 50 rows I need to assign a color and they all must be unique. What would be the easiest way to do this?

I do not want to do the alternating row colors:

```
"=IIf(RowNumber("DataSet1")  Mod 2 = 1, "White","Blue")",
```

but if there was a way to modify this expression to do 50 colors and then repeat I'd be okay with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use choose . otherwise use custom code function

```html
=Choose(ROWNUMBER(nothing) mod 50,  "Brown", "Blue",  "GoldenRod", "Olive", "MediumTurquoise","Red", "Green", "DeepSkyBlue", "Yellow", "Chocolate", "Purple", "DarkOrange" ,.....)
```